# asp:DropDownList - invalid postback or callback argument when adding options via JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I have two dropdown lists:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Field_Type" runat="server" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="Field_SubType" runat="server" />
```

`Field_Type` is databound, with a list of types, populated from a database. `Field_SubType` is set via jQuery / AJAX when `Field_Type` is changed. I then add an option using `$("#<%# Field_SubType.ClientID %>").append("<option value=\"1\">Test</option>");`. This works as expected (I see the new subtype added).

However, when posting back after selecting the option that has been added I get an error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

What could be the cause of this, and how could I work round it? A few ideas I have:

1. Use a plain `<select>` and use `Request.Form` - could be a problem if it is in a user control used multiple times on a page
2. Populate `Field_SubType` with all sub types, filtering out those that aren't a sub type of `Field_Type` - this will load more data than required, which will add to page load time

Any other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of it is that by default, ASP.NET verifies that the submitted values in each form field are the ones it sent to the page originally. Here is an example:

We have a DropDownList with 3 options - A, B, and C. ASP.NET knows about those because we added them from ASP.NET code. In JavaScript, we add a fourth option, D. ASP.NET does not know about that one because it happened on the client side. When we go to submit the page, if D is selected, ASP.NET says "D is not one of the choices I gave you. You may be maliciously trying to manipulate the post values in the request." It protects the system and the developer by aborting the request right there.

You could just turn off page validation - on the page in question, as the error message suggests, or for all pages at the web.config level:

```
<system.web>
   <pages enableEventValidation="false"/>
</system.web>
```

Event validation is not always necessary if you write your code in such a way that you never take explicit action directly based on the values submitted to you in the form (which you should never really do anyway). Unexpected or out-of-range values from the user should be ignored or cause you to do nothing. As long as you write your code that way, you can safely turn off event validation.

Comment: Rex, wouldn't this leave the whole site open to script injection?  I would just enable it on the pages where the control is used and provide extra validation for any other inputs on the page.

Comment: @Jim assuming you rely on that to prevent users submitting markup, it could. But who does that ;)

Comment: @Jim If you're only relying on page validation to prevent XSS, you have another problem entirely.  Use the latest version of the AntiXSS library to achieve a better level of security and run CAT.NET to uncover possible vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

This may also occur if you load your dropdown list with text that has not been trimmed.  I loaded a dropdown from XML and it placed newline chars and spaces in the items. However when the dropdown appeared everything looked fine.  Upon changing a dropdown I got the error.

Adding trim solved the problem:

```
items.Add(item2.Value.Trim());
```